# Can the integral get small outside a set with finite measure?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu )$ be a measure space and let $ f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{\overline{R}}$ integrable.

I just proved the fact that for every $\epsilon > 0$ we find $\delta > 0$ so that for every $A \in \mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(A)<\delta$ $$ \int_{A} |f| d\mu <\epsilon $$ holds.

Now I'm wondering if we can prove a similiar statement:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $A \in \mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(A) < \infty$ so that $$ \int_{X \setminus A} |f| d\mu <\epsilon $$

Is it possible to derive this statement directly from the one mentioned first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Let $A_n = \{x : |f(x)| \ge \frac{1}{n}\}$.  Note that if $f$ is integrable we must have $\mu(A_n) < \infty$ (Markov's inequality).  The sequence $|f| 1_{A_n}$ converges to $|f|$ pointwise and is dominated by the integrable function $|f|$, so we have $\int |f| 1_{A_n} \,d\mu\to \int |f|\,d\mu$.  Subtracting, $\int |f| (1 - 1_{A_n}) \,d\mu= \int_{X \setminus A_n} |f|\,d\mu \to 0$.  In particular, for any $\epsilon$, there exists $n$ sufficiently large that $\int_{X \setminus A_n} |f| < \epsilon$.

Note that we do not need to assume that $(X,\mu)$ is $\sigma$-finite.  (In fact, the support of $f$ is $\sigma$-finite even if $X$ itself is not.)

Answer (score 1):

This is true.  Just apply monotone convergence or dominated convergence to $|f|$ times the indicator function on $[-n,n]$.

Comment: Notice that the measure space is arbitrary.